# Can't fetch twitter user timeline using 1.1 API in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to write a small Twitter application. I have managed to run the authentication Python example from the Twitter documentation, and I can get data from "statuses/home_timeline.json", for instance.

But now I am trying to use "statuses/user_timeline.json", and no dice.

Here is the code I am using. It's just a modification from the example in the webpage. What can be wrong? I triple-checked the service URI. Isn't it correct?

I am using the python-oauth2-1.0.0 release from github, the project the documentation refers to but that is quite old. Is there a better module I should be using? There was an incorrect parameter in `client.request`, by the way.

Another thing: I can run the query using curl, with the command line created on the Twitter dev webpage.

```
import oauth2 as oauth

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET", post_body=None,
              http_headers=None):
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = oauth.Token(key=key, secret=secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

    resp, content = client.request(
        url,
        method=http_method,
        body=post_body,
        headers=http_headers
    )
    return content


# home_timeline = oauth_req(
#     'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json',
#     ACCESS_KEY,
#     ACCESS_SECRET
# )

home_timeline = oauth_req(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=3&screen_name=twitterapi',
    ACCESS_KEY,
    ACCESS_SECRET
)

print home_timeline
```

Comment: The error I get from the user_timeline query is:

    {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

Comment: We use exactly the above method to fetch tweets for a set of users. The differences are, we use user_id and specify just the "url" param in client.request call and this has been working fine for months. Can't spot any obvious bug as long as all data types (string, int etc.) are being specified correctly. HTTP404, code 34 is usually returned when the user account doesn't exist.

Comment: copy-pasted some more differences. try using include_rts=true. # prep resource URL with TwitterID: twit_url = twitter_statuses_user + 'user_id=' + str(twitID) +                       '&trim_user=true&exclude_replies=true&include_rts=true' +                                '&count=200' # max is 200

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [Twython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twython/) package. You can install it using:

```
pip install twython
```

or 
    easy_install twython

You can use the below code to get the user timeline

```
import twython
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
twitter = twython.Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
home_timeline = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name='@twitterapi')
print home_timeline
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I installed the most recent version of python-oauth2... Twitter really should update their docs. Thanks everyone for the help!